# jQuery FancyBox stopping ASP.NET Logout link from working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am using the FancyBox jQuery plugin (http://fancybox.net/) in my ASP.NET website and have hit a small but annoying issue.

The site uses the default ASP.NET login controls and then displays some links which pop open a form in a FancyBox - all this works great. If I *do not* click any of the FancyBox links and then hit the logout link (provided by the LoginStatus control) again everything works as it should.

However if I click on one of the FancyBox links and then close it the logout link no longer works, nothing happens at all - it would appear as if the postback is not firing for some reason.

I have done some searching but not come across anyone with a similar issue - has anyone seen this issue before?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: With a little help from IE debugger I have tracked the problem down to a JavaScript error here -

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

More specifically on the line that sets the eventtarget and the error I recieve is -

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

UPDATE 2: I have put a temporary fix in place - basically I just hook into the onClosed event and reload the page at that point -

```
$("#form_popup").fancybox({ 
'scrolling': 'no', 
'titleShow': true, 
'onClosed' : function() { 
    location.reload(); 
} });
```

Of course the problem is the page will be fully reloaded from scratch missing the point of using jQuery but at least it works!

Comment: @KevinMain you should use the "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag to force your web page into IE8 mode see if this helps

Comment: Hi @Devjosh, thanks for your suggestion but didn't make any difference - also tested across other browsers and get the same result so confident it is not a browser issue.

Comment: what error do you get in firebug console in firefox @KevinMain

Comment: Hmm..interesting FireFox is the only browser it seems to work in but I get the following error in Firebug 

Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlBehavior' cannot be converted to type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlBehavior'. Parameter name: instance

Comment: Are you using jQuery in noConflict mode? Fancybox takes a clone of #form_popup, so you will have TWO #form_popup in your DOM. Maybe this interfer someway?

Comment: Thanks @SimonEdström, that was my initial thought so tried noConflict() but seemed to make no difference, although I am pretty sure the issue is something along those lines - just not worked out what yet.

Comment: Are you using iframe? Play around a bit with the console and see if this is null: theForm.__EVENTTARGET or theForm (I think you can execute it directly in IE console, or switch to Chrome and just to the test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem I fixed this with this hack

```
$("#form_popup").fancybox({ 
 'scrolling': 'no', 
 'titleShow': true, 
 'onClosed' : function() { 
 location.reload(); 
} });
```

So the page gets reloaded whenever the close button is pushed which fixes the problem.