# TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function with asp:LoginStatus

Tags: asp.net, loginstatus

i found one similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157976/jquery-fancybox-stopping-asp-net-logout-link-from-working) but i'm not sure how to apply it here, or if it can be.

the problem is that the asp:LoginStatus button is doing nothing; i can't log out.

the javascript error is:

```
TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function
theForm.submit();
```

which is coming from script that is injected by asp.net:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

i watched __doPostBack. eventArgument is not getting a value. not sure if that's the real problem though.

```
eventTarget   : "ctl00$HeadLoginView$HeadLoginStatus$ctl00"
eventArgument : ""
```

any ideas as to why the asp:LoginStatus button is doing nothing?

Comment: the status btn is in a user control (no caching). when i hover over the logout btn, this is the link: javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$NavMainCtrl$HeadLoginView$HeadLoginStatus$ctl00',''). -- does this control always use javascript __doPostBack? also, should the second param have a value?

Answer (score 8):

sry to bother you all with this. after two days i just figured out the problem: i put a paypal button on the page, along with a paypal image.

```
<img src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif' id="submit" alt='Donate' />
```

that image was inside the anchor/link to paypal, but i'm quite sure the real problem was **id="submit"**. the form did not like that.

Comment: Thanks for "bothering" everyone!!  I just stumbled on this and with your help I solved it in 15 minutes instead of 2 days.

Comment: Please, you can always "bother". I'd never find this by myself! Thanks!

Comment: this answer was useful even after almost 7 years...